# Sony PCM-M10: safety track?

Tags: audio-recording, field-recording, production-audio, pcm-m10, m10

Suppose I feed an actress' mono lavalier mic into M10's Line-in.

AFAIK there is no built-in safety track feature on M10, where I could set one channel's level to be say 12dB lower in case she yells.

On the other hand, since I keep Limiter (but not AGC) always engaged, do we even need safety track? I hear you can't overload M10 with Limiter on - is it true?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know that equipment, so this is not really an answer

but... even though hitting the limiter would not allow it to go over-meter, it's not going to sound nice. You'll hear it suddenly flat-line.

If you've no other safety-net, I'd suggest testing before-hand how much noise-floor you perceptively gain at -6 or -12 & see which you can live with.

I remember back at the BBC in the late 80s, that even on then state-of-the-art 16-bit gear, they would always run regular program peaks at -12; as being better to have overhead & noise-floor than ever hit the [in those days totally unforgiving] red-line.

I'd always say, if it's good enough for the Beeb, it's good enough for me ;)

Comment: Yes I'm sure it won't sound too nice on a limiter. With Line-in and mono signal, I could make my own plug with one channel attenuated -12dB with resistors (since M10 doesn't seem to have built-in safety track function.) But will it work with lav, which gets its power from the connector??

Comment: that I don't know, sorry; it's not equipment I've used. You'd still at one point in the circuit have to be prepared for either over-level, or allow 12dB headroom, even if it's in the preamp